# Comparison of two tables based on a cross reference of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question is about comparison of fields based on the mapping table SQL Server. In the attached image, I wanted to compare values of Table 1 and Table 2 based on the mapping provided in Table 3. For example, we need to check values of Table 1's `Field 1` with Table 2's `Field_3_New` and other columns likewise. Mapping of these columns to compare is placed in Table 3.

[image]

I want to check, whether Table 1's `Field 1` values are matching with Table 2's `Field 3_NEW`'s values or not. We came to know that Table 1's `Field 1` values have a match with Table 2's `Field 3_New` values based on the field mapping provided in Table 3. The above is an example scenario, I'm dealing with 40 odd fields like this.

Comment: I need clarification. Are you trying to create "Table 3" based on the data from "Table 1" and "Table2"? Or trying to create output based on three tables? In later provide the expected output

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for, you need to provide the output your are looking for.

Comment: I want to check, whether Table 1's Field 1 values are matching with Table 2's Field 3_NEW's values or not. We came to know that Table 1's field 1 values have a match with Table 2's Field 3_New values based on the field mapping provided in the Table 3. The above is an example scenario, I'm dealing with 40 odd fields like this.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how each row in TABLE 1 compares against every value in TABLE 2 and whether each column matches-- (e.g. a result with 16 rows showing how the matches align) or can you assume one of these mappings is a primary key mapping and you want to join by that and then compare the remaining columns? (e.g a result with 4 rows, where table 1 is joined to table 2 by Field 1 <--> Field 3_New and showing whether Field 2 = Fields 1_NEW and Field 3 = Field 2_New)?